# Summarize pair of occurrences ignoring directionality

Tags: r, igraph

Given certain events, for example people sitting together around a table, I would like to summarize these as frequencies of pairs. In other words, how often do two elements appear consecutively/adjoined? The twist is that `A B` and `B A` should count as two since I am not interested if `A` comes before `B` only that they appear together. Example data:

```
events <- list()
events[["week_1"]] <- c("A", "B", "C")
events[["week_2"]] <- c("A", "B")
events[["week_3"]] <- c("A", "C", "B")
```

from this I can create [pairs of elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26370581/extract-consecutive-pairs-of-elements-from-a-vector-and-place-in-a-matrix):

```
createPairs <- function(x){
    data.frame(cbind(x[-length(x)], x[-1]))
}
pairs_l <- lapply(events, createPairs)
pairs <- do.call("rbind", pairs_l)
pairs

week_1.1  A  B
week_1.2  B  C
week_2    A  B
week_3.1  A  C
week_3.2  C  B
```

The issue comes with summarizing, which takes the two columns into account, but in a certain order:

```
library(plyr)
pairs_count <- ddply(pairs,.(X1, X2),nrow)
pairs_count

  X1 X2 V1
1  A  B  2
2  A  C  1
3  B  C  1
4  C  B  1
```

Note lines 3 and 4. These are thorny ones that I would like to summarize together so that in the end:

```
  X1 X2 V1
1  A  B  2
2  A  C  1
3  B  C  2
```

I have tried multiple summarization/aggregation strategies, and they all failed.

---

What is the end game? I would like to create a network of people sitting together using `igraph` and for that the data needs to in a format similar to (random example):

```
>   from  to weight      type
> 1  s01 s02     10 hyperlink
> 2  s01 s02     12 hyperlink
> 3  s01 s03     22 hyperlink
> 4  s01 s04     21 hyperlink
> 5  s04 s11     22   mention
> 6  s05 s15     21   mention
```

or as an adjacency matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with `dplyr`. I had to change your function to disallow factors. I then create a key using `pmin` and `pmax` and `summarise` on this new data:

```
events <- list()
events[["week_1"]] <- c("A", "B", "C")
events[["week_2"]] <- c("A", "B")
events[["week_3"]] <- c("A", "C", "B")

createPairs <- function(x){
    data.frame(cbind(x[-length(x)], x[-1]), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)  #changes
}
pairs_l <- lapply(events, createPairs)
pairs <- do.call("rbind", pairs_l)

pairs %>%
rowwise() %>%
mutate(key = paste0(pmin(X1, X2), pmax(X1, X2), sep = "")) %>%
group_by(key) %>%
summarise(X1=min(X1, X2),X2=max(X1, X2),total.count=n())

    key    X1    X2 total.count
  <chr> <chr> <chr>       <int>
1    AB     A     B           2
2    AC     A     C           1
3    BC     B     C           2
```